# Would a German transit visa serve my purpose?

Tags: schengen, airports, germany, transit-visas, lufthansa

I plan to purchase a​ ​​Lufthansa return air ticket, from ​New Delhi, India, to Mexico City​ this May​​. The departing flight has a 5h 50m layover in Frankfurt and the returning flight has a 7h 10m layover in Munich. So, the itinerary is Delhi-Frankfurt-Mexico City and Mexico City-Munich-Delhi.

I have a Bangladeshi passport, with an Indian visa and a Mexican visa. I am planning to apply for a German transit visa (Category A).

I have read that I can't use this category of German visa if I have to pick up my baggage and/or have to check-in again at the transit airport. Will I be able to travel without trouble with these travel documents on this Lufthansa flight? That is, does Lufthansa provide adequate support at the ​departure/transit ​terminal to make sure that I ​don't need to leave the international transit area, stay air-side and don't need to pass through border control/immigration in transit?

And also, is it easier to get the ATV than the usual Schengen visas? I emailed the consulate and they replied that I don't need to submit any financial documents. Hence, I think it should be rather straightforward, right?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "support", but the Frankfurt Airport has many airside cafes, at least one bookstore with some English works, and I managed to catch a nap in one of the seats although that wasn't easy. Is there a more specific need? Note also that there are visas you may already hold (Mexico is _not_ one of them) that eliminate the need for the transit visa. See the [canonical](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area) answer.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus not at all concerned with the airport airside facilities, although now that I know of it, wouldn't hurt to have a good read. I actually was asking about Lufthansa's support at the transit, whether they would give me both the boarding pass at Delhi or will there be a counter at the airside, ensuring that I won't need to leave airside for any reason at all. I have checked and found that I will be needing a transit visa. Sorry for the confusing wording, and thanks.

Comment: Assuming this is one ticket, you will probably get the boarding pass in Delhi, but if this is not possible for some reason, there is airside customer service.

Comment: Consider transiting elsewhere. For instance DEL-FCO-MEX on Alitalia. You would [not need a transit visa to transit through Italy](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=IN&DE=MX&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=IT&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX).

Comment: I am a Bangladeshi passport holder, not Indian, so I think unfortunately I would actually need a visa to transit Italy :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you will be able to transit in both Frankfurt and Munich on Lufthansa with an ATV if all your flights are booked on the same ticket.** In this case, you will be given your boarding passes for each leg of your flight at the point of departure (Delhi on your outbound trip, and Mexico City on your inbound trip). Your bags will also be checked till the final destination. At no point during your transit will you enter the Schengen Zone. If, for whatever reason, you are not issued boarding passes for the whole trip at the two points of departure, you will be able to collect them at the transit airport at Lufthansa's customer assistance counter.

Source: I'm a frequent flier on Lufthansa transiting through FRA and MUC often.